# Handling 'A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client' and informing user of this error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

i'm trying to handle the following issue

> 'A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client'

However, I can't find a good tutorial which explains how to catch this error and handle it. Just to be clear I want to stop users from entering any sort of markup when filling out my form. Most of the articles dealing with this issue suggest turning off request validation. This is not something I want to do. I want to catch the error and playback the error to the user. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to allow HTML, but simply strip any markup from the input value?

Comment: @TiesonT. There's *lots* of stuff / various attacks that gets filtered out by this validation - thinking you can do it better than ASP.Net is naive.

Comment: @caesay I'm not suggesting turning off request validation. I'm suggesting adding the AllowHtmlAttribute to whatever model the OP is using and then sanitizing the input.

Comment: "and then sanitizing the input" is very hard to get complete and safe. Denying everything but safe/expected is much more reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch the error with an exception filter. Something like:

```
public class RequestValidationExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.Exception is HttpRequestValidationException)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Error");
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You can get some more info in the `Message` of the exception, e.g.:

> A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (FilterName="<script>alert("!!")<...").

But that is not really something to be shown to the user. So best thing to do would be a redirect to some generic error page. Or you can send them back to the current page.

Comment: is there any way of adding an error to the modelstate so I can replay this error back to the user? But i would make the error message more generic.

Comment: Well, at this point in an exception filter we are already out of the controller. So I do not think so. If you were able to replace the component that throws the error, maybe you could add the error to modelstate..

Comment: Or maybe if an action filter runs before the error is thrown you could validate it with the same component it uses internally, add the modelstate error and erase the value in the model so the error does not get thrown. But if it's thrown during model binding then this won't work..

Answer (score 0):

I was doing some quick testing just now, and for some reason action filters and exception filters were not getting executed for me when the validation exception was happening - so I whipped up something quick using `Application_Error()`. (you can create this method in `Global.asax.cs` if it does not already exist)

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var lastError = Server.GetLastError() as HttpRequestValidationException;
    if (lastError == null)
        return;

    MvcHandler mvcHandler = Context.CurrentHandler as MvcHandler;
    if (mvcHandler == null)
        return;

    RequestContext requestContext = mvcHandler.RequestContext;
    if (requestContext == null)
        return;

    Server.ClearError();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

    // pick one of the following two options, or maybe more?
    RedirectToUrl(requestContext);
    ExecuteActionResult(requestContext, ...);

}

void ExecuteActionResult(RequestContext requestContext, ActionResult result)
{
    string controllerName = requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    IControllerFactory factory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
    IController controller = factory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
    ControllerContext controllerContext = new ControllerContext(requestContext, (ControllerBase)controller);
    result.ExecuteResult(controllerContext);
}

void RedirectToUrl(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    requestContext.HttpContext.Server.TransferRequest($"~/Error/Something", false);
}
```

I included an example of how to redirect to an arbitrary url, and also an example of how to execute a new `ActionResult` against the same controller that the original request was executed on.